# How to use Spectral Temporal Metric (reducers) in Supervised Random Forest Classification in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-classification

I am trying to improve image classification in GEE by using the STM of the mean.
I first calculated the mean of the four bands.

Then I added the new column with **mean** to the image.

Then I used the new image with 5 bands (including the mean)  to classify.

However, I keep getting errors in my classification. Here is my code:

```
Map.addLayer(image, imageVisParam);
Map.centerObject(image,11);

//select the bands 
var bands = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'];

var stm = image.select(bands).reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).rename('STM')
print(stm)

var classNames = Water.merge(BuiltupArea).merge(Cropland).merge(Vegetation).merge(Wetland).merge(clouds)
print(classNames);

var imageWithSTM = image.addBands(stm)

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(50)
  .train({
    features: classNames,
    classProperty: 'Class', 
    inputProperties: bands.concat(['STM'])
  });
  
print(classifier, 'classifier')

var classified = imageWithSTM.classify(classifier)


print(classified, 'classified');

//Add the classification to the map view, specify colours for classes
Map.addLayer(classified,
{min: 0, max: 5, palette: ['0000FF', 'FF0000', '008000','FFFF00','98ff00','ffc82d']},
'classification')
```

I get this error when I run the codes: **Image (Error) Property 'b1' of feature '0' is missing.** **classification: Layer error: Property 'b1' of feature '0' is missing.**

How can I change my code to use all five bands or more  in the classification without getting an error?

Comment: What error do you get? Include your asset and training data in the code, so the error can be replicated. Make sure the assets are shared.

Comment: Please share the particular code snippet rather the whole repository link.

Comment: @Padmanabha I have edited the question with the code snippet

Comment: Perhaps feature 0 is outside the bounds of the image? check https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/debugging#running-a-function-on-first

Comment: It seems like that's not the case. When I run the classification using the same training data but without the additional STM column, it functions perfectly. The issue seems to have been introduced when I added the new field.